# How to access a local image resource from Cocoa webview?

Tags: macos, cocoa, browser, webview, safari

How to access a local image resource from the path in Cocoa webview?

```
NSURLRequest *requst = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.1.24.23:8080"]];
    [_webView.mainFrame loadRequest:requst];

<img src="file:///Users/xxx/xxx">
```

The above code returns

> Not allowed to load local resource

in the Safari inspector. 
Is it even possible to load a local resource in Safari？

Comment: Please rephrase your question, use "?" and "." properly so one does not need to spend eternity decoding what you were trying to ask.

Comment: sorry ，i edit my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to reference local resource from a web page, located on a web server. That will not work because of security limitations. Those limitations are totally sane, it's the main thing why evil hackers can't easily access any files on your mac just by opening a web page in your browser.

You have 2 options to resolve this issue. Either move the local file to the same server, where the web page is located. Or do vice versa - open a local web page. For example, you can download html and related resources, store them locally and open downloaded file in a web view. You can also consider running HTTP server locally for your application, f.e. [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer).

In case if I've misunderstood your question, and no html page is involved, my recommendations still should remain valid.

Comment: I started thinking that I could configure a property like windows so that I could debug it temporarily. It seems impossible.Very sorry, my English is poor. Please forgive my Chinese English. Haha. . .